# How set cron to run not only in exact time

Tags: .net, cron

My cron is "0 */30 11-12 * * * *"

It will work in 11:00, 11:30, 12:00, 12:30.

If I will start application in 12:31, cron will not triggered, but I need start it in any situation, how can I do it?

I use .Net Console application, and NCrontab

Answer (score 0):

Add a cron start script in your application file.
For eg., If you want to restart cron job, whenever you restart apache application, then add a start script which restarts your cron job in apache application starting script.